# python for loop on subprocess.Popen() and os.system() i get TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

Say i have written bellow code:

```
import os
import subprocess

 for i in os.system('ls'):
    print i
```

I have got the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

When i try to do the same with subprocess.Popen

```
 for i in subprocess.Popen("ls" , shell=True).wait():
    print i
```

I have the same problem . if i do only do os.system('ls') or subprocess.Popen("ls" , shell=True).wait()

```
  db.sqlite3  ip  manage.py  mysite  
  0
```

The extra '0' that coming after the output is giving problem . Any way to get rid of it ?

Comment: `0` is the return code from the process. It means it ran without problems.

Comment: What are you expecting `system` to return that you can iterate over? The result of calling `ls` is output sent to `sys.stdout`.

Comment: thats ok , how to get rid of the error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: If you want to list the directory, do it in python [**`os.iistdir`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list you can iterate over.

Comment: don't try to iterate using the process return code

Comment: what if i want to list out only files , i dont want to list the directories.

Comment: Thanks any way , finally i got the ans .      files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]    ; for i in files:   print i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system()` [returns the return value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) (0 if successful).

For obvious reasons you can't iterate on an integer so you have to get iterable data.

You want to get the string that is the output, parse it, and iterate over it.
The [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function should be your way to go.

Comment: Thanks that was i looking for .

Answer (score 0):

If you want stdout:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ls", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    print(line)
```